# Plotting graph in C3.js using array

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have two arrays. One is of names (nameArray) and the other is of count(countArray). 
The values for the arrays will be obtained through an API.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
      ]
    }
});
```

The above code sample is available from C3.js website . I need it to behave differently.

Sample arrays:-

```
nameArray=["name1","name2","name3"]
countArray=[20,34,12]
```

In this example , I want names to be along X-axis and count to be along Y-Axis.
Please help me achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C3 has an option to accept [Row Oriented Data](http://c3js.org/samples/data_rowed.html):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    rows: [
            ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
            [90, 120, 300],
            [40, 160, 240],
            [50, 200, 290],
            [120, 160, 230],
            [80, 130, 300],
            [90, 220, 320],
        ]
    }
});
```

Isn't that what you want?
You just need to merge `nameArray` and `countArray` to array of arrays:

```
var data = [];
data.push(nameArray);
//do this for each count array
data.push(countArray);
```

Then do:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: { rows: data }
});
```

**Edit**

I think I follow you now. Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RzNrQ16Njrm1k3eVjGlf?p=preview) what you want?

In this case you need [Category Axis](http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html) feature.
To prepare data you have to do the following:

```
//your arrays
var nameArray=["name1","name2","name3"]
var countArray=[20,34,12]

countArray.unshift('data');

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
      columns: [countArray]
    },
    axis:{
      x:{
        type: 'category',
        categories: nameArray
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't hard code data like that, since my data is dynamic . I need to plot it using arrays. For both X and Y axis. Thanks

Comment: then do not hardcode, merge your dynamic arrays and draw a chart.

Comment: The arrays are not supposed to be separate rows.Name array is X axis and Count array is Y axis. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Vinay, I'm not sure I follow you. Could you please update your question with examples of those arrays?

Comment: @ ieaglle, can you take a look again ? I hope I have been clear. Thanks again.